# how to set FireFox cookies to persist if browser closed

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

When I close a Firefox browser, and re-open, the cookies are gone.
How is this controlled?

I want to maintain certain user preferences/options in cookies.

Am using Firefox 10.0.2 on Windows-vista.

Comment: "the cookies": What cookies? *All* your cookies? Or the cookies you set from a website that you're developing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is simply to set the expiration using this, each time a cookie is written:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
 {
 var exdate=new Date();
 exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
 document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This applies to Firefox 8, so may still work for Firefox 10. (I'm downloading the update now to check and will update my answer accordingly)

Go to Tools -> Options -> Privacy.

Under History there is a section which says "Firefox will:". If this is set to "Use custom settings for History" you can choose whether to accept cookies or not and whether to keep them until they expire, or until you close Firefox.

**Edit:** This procedure is still the same in Firefox 10

Also, I want to note that this should be the default behaviour of Firefox if set to "Firefox will: Remember History".

Answer (score 1):

For me, Win 7 Firefox (10.0.2) I hit alt, go to tools (at top of firefox) options then got to privacy tab. There I can select from 3 options: remember history, never remember history, custom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has been set to Remember.
But the cookies my web creates get eaten when I close the browser.

Comment: If you go to privacy tab and select custom settings you should see a keep until drop down box, you can then select: they expire, i close firefox or ask me every time. Also if you hit show cookies can you see yours? And can you see an expiration date?

Comment: Thank.
I can see my cookies, but they have: "Expires: At end of session."
Cookies from other web sites, like Google, have their "Expires: Monday, March 04, 2013 2:57:55 PM"
Can FireFox be configured to always keep cookies?
Or, must I programmatically in JavaScript set the expiration?  (I'll put how to in the answer.)

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html try this site - it says if you dont specify and expiration then the cookie is trashed when you close the browser - also further down tells you how to set the expiration date - hope this solves your problem